# Effects of Game-based Learning on Motivation for Learning

Tags: teaching, online-learning, motivation, learning

I found many studies discovering the impact of game-based learning on motivation for learning.

[For example, these papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=game-based+learning+impact+motivation)

You can also find a summary of them in [this book chapter](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-3185-5_38).

However, it is still unclear to me if this motivation is for entertainment or for learning. I was wondering if there is any study showing that students who are adapted to this method of learning have a higher motivation to pursue learning in other forms. My concern is about long-term effects of this method of learning. What is the intrinsic reaction of K-12 students who have adapted to game-based learning when they start higher education in which game-based learning is not provided? Will they have a higher incentive to study? or a lower incentive, because they prefer to play games rather than studying?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, though I have only few knowledge about it... But I believe, when things are learned playfully- it is more effective. The game genre also matters, especially when different subjects require different skills to learn...

Comment: Since game-based learning is a rather new thing (as I understand), I can't imagine too much has been done regarding long-term studies.

Comment: Game based learning isn't that terribly new. I grew up on Reader Rabbit, Math Blaster, and Carmen Sandiego, etc. Anecdotally, they were helpful, but I'm less convinced of the Second Life-style game made for one of the intro textbooks that my department uses :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a higher ed instructional designer. Our industry is beginning to integrate **serious games**(a term that seems to be replacing educational games) and the principles of gamification into our courses, particularly those that are online. We know that K-12 students are using Learning Management Systems, mobile devices, and games to learn (whether formally or informally), so we are getting ready for them.

**On gaming versus studying:** A well-designed serious game and/or gameified learning environment IS studying. Instructional designers like myself who are present on a team developing a gamified online unit of instruction or course are there to ensure that pedagogical best practices are embedded in the content. I can't really answer a generalized statement about higher or lower incentives/motivation because no specific audience has been defined. Individuals, and their reaction to different types of curriculum, vary.

Comment: thank you for your response. Where can I find resources and tools to apply game-based learning in the courses I teach?

Comment: I would search online using such keywords as, "gamification" and "serious gaming" in addition to keywords related to what you teach (if you taught English Comp I in higher ed, for example, you'd add keywords like "English", "higher ed", etc.). When starting out, it helps to see how to apply such principles to your specific subject and grade level.